# Como puedo implementar Clases anidadas en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Alguna idea de como puedo implementar lo siguiente en javascript, necesito que los hijos tengan acceso a las propiedades y metodos de la madre y que se puedan crear x cantidad de hijos a partir de la madre

```
class Mom {
     constructor(name) {
         this.name = name
     }

     presentation() {
         console.log('my name is ' + this.name)
     }

     class Son{
          constructor(name) {
             this.name = name
          }

          presentation() {
               console.log('my name is ' + this.name + ' and my mom is ' + super.name)
          }
     }
 }

 theMom = new Mom('Maria')
 theSon = new theMom.Son('Jose')

 theMom.presentation()
 theSon.presentation() // my name is Jose and my mom is Maria

 thenSon2 = new theMom.Son('Andrea')

 thenSon2.presentation() // my name is Andrea and my mom is Maria
```

Comment: Creo que Javascript no esta hecho para eso... igual te dejo la documentación por si no haz leido https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Te recomiendo mejor que trabajes con Arrays donde el array principal sea Madre y dentro de madre colocas a los hijos, creo que hasta más sencillo seria

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que quieres `Son` puede guardar una referencia a `Mom` para acceder a sus propiedades.

```js
class Son {
    constructor(name, mom) {
        this.name = name
        this.mom = mom
    }
    presentation() {
        console.log('my name is ' + this.name + ' and my mom is ' + this.mom.name)
    }
}

class Mom {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
        this.sons = []
    }

    createSon(name) {
        let son = new Son(name, this)
        this.sons.push(son)
        return son
    }
    presentation() {
        console.log('my name is ' + this.name)
    }
}




let mom = new Mom("Maria")
let son = mom.createSon("carlos")

mom.presentation();
son.presentation();
```